# knockout foreach numeric array

Tags: javascript, knockout.js, durandal

i have this array:

```
[{"room_id":"1","room_name":"CDI","workers":[[{"worker_id":"12","worker_name":"FF","worker_grade":"Q2"},{"worker_id":"13","worker_name":"Test","worker_grade":"Q1"}],[{"worker_id":"12","worker_name":"FF","worker_grade":"Q2"},{"worker_id":"13","worker_name":"Test","worker_grade":"Q1"}],[],[],[{"worker_id":"13","worker_name":"Test","worker_grade":"Q1"}]]},{"room_id":"2","room_name":"DD","workers":[[],[],[],[{"worker_id":"12","worker_name":"FF","worker_grade":"Q2"},{"worker_id":"13","worker_name":"Test","worker_grade":"Q1"}],[]]}]
```

My problem is a loop in y viewmodel:

```
 <tbody data-bind="foreach: rooms">
            <tr>
                <th data-bind="text: room_name"></th>
                <!--ko foreach: workers-->
                <td>
                <!--ko foreach: 0-->
                <!--ko text: worker_name--><!--/ko-->
                    <!--/ko-->
                </td>
                <td>
                    <!--ko foreach: 1-->
                    <!--ko text: worker_name--><!--/ko-->
                    <!--/ko-->
                </td>
                <td>
                    <!--ko foreach: 2-->
                    <!--ko text: worker_name--><!--/ko-->
                    <!--/ko-->
                </td>
                <td>
                    <!--ko foreach: 3-->
                    <!--ko text: worker_name--><!--/ko-->
                    <!--/ko-->
                </td>
                <td>
                    <!--ko foreach: 4-->
                    <!--ko text: worker_name--><!--/ko-->
                    <!--/ko-->
                </td>
                <!--/ko-->
            </tr>
        </tbody>
```

Because the arrays after workers aren't associative, I can't cycle  through  it. But how can I now go   through it and display the other arrays like:

```
[{"worker_id":"12","worker_name":"Adriaan Wind","worker_grade":"Q2"},{"worker_id":"13","worker_name":"Test","worker_grade":"Q1"}]
```

The solution above doesn't work.

Comment: well `fibi` i hope this is what you are  looking at check fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/supercool/74dh736s/44/ .

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to add name like "rooms" for room binding and "workers" for the workers related bindings. And then you can bind your details in following manner

```js
 ko.applyBindings(
     { "rooms" : [{ "room_id":"1","room_name":"CDI",
       "workers":[{"worker_id":"12",                                                                          "worker_name":"FF",
                    "worker_grade":"Q2"},
                  {"worker_id":"13", 
                   "worker_name":"Test",
                   "worker_grade":"Q1"}
                 ]}
                 ]});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/knockout/3.0.0/knockout-min.js"></script>
<div data-bind="foreach: rooms">
    Room <span data-bind="text:room_name "></span>
    <div data-bind="foreach: workers">
        Worker: <span data-bind="text: worker_name"></span><hr/>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: good try `Dnyanesh` there should be check's if properties are undefined (acc to OP's json) . you can look into the fiddle in comments - cheers